# system python/pip binary being used in virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I am new to virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper, but if I understand things correctly, when I create and workon a new virtualenv it should be using the python binary in the environment (in my case, `.virtualenvs/foo/bin/python`).

However, when I `workon foo` I am noticing that it is not pointing to that python binary:

```
 me@crixalis ~ which python
 /usr/local/bin/python
 me@crixalis ~ workon foo
 (foo) me@crixalis ~ which python
 /usr/local/bin/python
 (foo) me@crixalis ~
```

`pip` has the same problem. I haven't done anything except add the following to my .zshrc:

```
# Virtualenv
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/devel
source /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Where's `workon` coming from? I usually use `source /path/to/env/bin/activate`.

Comment: virtualenvwrapper. i can `source /path/to/env/bin/activate` and have the same issue.

Comment: Have you moved the directory with the virtualenv in? IIRC the path to the new bin directory is hardcoded.

Comment: That was it! I moved it from `virtualenvs` to `.virtualenvs` per recommendation by a site after i had created my first environment.